# XCode IOS Apple LLVM 3.1 - Eigen NEON breaks

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, eigen, clang++

The problem might involve using Apple's LLVM 3.1 Compiler and I am sure can be fixed by disabling NEON.  However we would like to use NEON.

I am also quite positive this is an error with my setup in XCode but it could be with Apple.  Really I'm just reaching out for some tips in the right direction.

```
/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h
188:Unknown type name 'namespace'
188: Expected ';' after top level declarator

/Eigen/Core
144:'cerrno' file not found

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/3.1/include/arm_neon.h
55: Unknown type name 'float32_t'
```

This missing float32_t error occurs every instance in that file.  Even though line 33 the typedef is clearly done.

**UPDATE:**
If I force `#define EIGEN_NO_DEBUG` then the only error remaining is the missing cerrno.  In fact it appears all the cXXX libs are missing (cstdlib for example).  Yet they work if I include them outside of Eigen.

Comment: The first error makes me think that you are compiling with clang instead of clang++, or atleast using a c compiler instead of a c++ one.

Comment: The file I'm including some C++ files from (which include Eigen) is an  .mm file so I assume it would be using clang++.  I haven't figured out how to tell XCode to show me its compiler log so I really see what it is doing.

Comment: Thanks to sharth.  The problem was discovered.

Under "SupportingFiles" was main.m.  This means clang was being used to compile main.m which included the files and eventually lead to Eigen being compiled with the wrong compiler.  I am surprised there was not a million more errors.

Rename main.m to main.mm, problems solved.

I cannot answer my own question yet... +1 rep short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue was that the source code was being compiled as Objective-C instead of Objective-C++. Fixing this fixed the issues.

Specifically caused by a file (main.m) not being renamed to (main.mm).  If you are renaming your files to .mm so it used ObjC++ (clang++) then make sure you get them all.